# Form.io form builder how to emit or submit data

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

I am building a dynamic drag and drop form builder and i cant find a way to console log out the data of the form. here is the form `component.html` in which i am rendering the drag and drop form

```html
 <div>
    
    <form-builder [form]="form" (change)="onChange($event)" (submit)="onSubmit($event)"></form-builder>
    
    <div class="well jsonviewer">
      <pre id="json"><code class="language-json" #json></code></pre>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

And here is the `component.ts` I just wanted to console the form data out then I will send it to the
API to be saved.

```js
    import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-user-add',
      templateUrl: './user-add.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./user-add.component.css']
    })
    export class UserAddComponent implements OnInit {
      title = 'ASW Form Builder Demo';
      jsonData:any[]=[];
      @ViewChild('json') jsonElement?: ElementRef;
    
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
      // Publish Template
      saveJsonData(data: any){
        //.... 
        console.log(data);
        // do something
      }
      
      //Preview Template
      previewTemplate(data: any){
        this.jsonData = data;
      }
    
      public form: Object = {components: []};
      onChange(event) {
        console.log(event.form);
      }
    
      onSubmit(param){
      console.log(param);
      }
    }
```

Can anyone help me fetch the data from the form on submit? and can i do this on another division and button outside the form? I wanted to use my own submit button. or is there any tutorial that can explain this starting from the database design?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to attach entire form object to your ts variable. Below is the code snippet that works for me.

**HTML**

```
 <div>
    
    <form-builder [form]="form" (change)="onChange($event)" (submit)="onSubmit($event)" #formio></form-builder>
    
    <div class="well jsonviewer">
      <pre id="json"><code class="language-json" #json></code></pre>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

**ts**

```
   import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-user-add',
      templateUrl: './user-add.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./user-add.component.css']
    })
    export class UserAddComponent implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild('formio') formIO: any;
      title = 'ASW Form Builder Demo';
      jsonData:any[]=[];
      @ViewChild('json') jsonElement?: ElementRef;

    
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
      // Publish Template
      saveJsonData(data: any){
        //.... 
        console.log(data);
        // do something
      }
      
      //Preview Template
      previewTemplate(data: any){
        this.jsonData = data;
      }
    
      public form: Object = {components: []};
      onChange(event) {
        console.log(event.form);
      }
    
      onSubmit(param){
       // You can use this.formIO.form to get the entire json
      console.log(this.formIO.form);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I saw you are using asw form builder which is easy to use and creates rapid development and design web forms that includes several controls.

Firstly, you need to create a form with the help of asw form builder with submit button after that once you will click on the submit button form builder will be emitting the JSON data in submit method.

like for example:

HTML Code:

```
<asw-form-builder [uploadData]="jsonData1"
            [isShowPreviewButton]="isShowPreviewButton"
            [isShowJsonDataButton]="isShowJsonDataButton"
            [isShowPublishButton]="isShowPublishButton"
            (publishClick)="saveJsonData($event)" 
            (previewClick)="previewTemplate($event)"
            (buttonClick)="buttonClick($event)"
            (aswModelChange)="onSelectionChange($event)"></asw-form-builder>
```

Component code:

```
export class AppComponent {
title = 'ASW Form Builder Demo';
jsonData: any[] = [];
jsonData1: any[] = [];
isShowPreviewButton = false;
isShowJsonDataButton = true;
isShowPublishButton = false;

// Publish Template
saveJsonData(data: any){
    //.... 
    console.log(data);
    // do something
}

//Preview Template
previewTemplate(data: any){
    this.jsonData = data;
}

// when you click on submit button form builder will call this method
buttonClick(data: any): void {
    console.log(data);
}

// form builder will call this method when any control model will be changed 
onSelectionChange(control: any): void {
    console.log(control);
}
```

}

HTML code for preview created form:

```
<asw-preview-template [formContainer]="jsonData" 
(buttonClick)="buttonClick($event)"
(aswModelChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
```

button click and onSelectionChange method should be the same as it is
below is the GitHub URL for the demo and documentation
https://github.com/asoftwareworld/ASW-Form-Builder

Please let us know if you need any help on this